# Nuxt.jsとSpringBootによるSPA・RestApiの設計について

Tags: docker, spring-boot, nuxt.js, axios

現在、Nuxt.jsとSpringBootによるSPA・RestApiのWebアプリケーションの開発を考えております。
ローカルでの開発では
・フロントエンドをdevサーバ（3000）で起動
・バックエンドをSpringBoot（8080）で起動
として、別々のサーバで動かせばうまくいくとは思いますが、
本番での運用方法がいまいちわかっていません。

SpringBootのプロジェクトにSPAのファイル群を
jarファイルにまとめて、dockerで動かすのが理想ですが、
こんなことできるのでしょうか。

特に不明な点は、
Nuxt.jsを使用してフロントエンド開発を行った場合、
devサーバを使わずに、静的リソースとして扱えるのかどうか
です。

よろしくお願い致します。

【開発環境】
Java 8
Spring Boot 2.1.1 
gradle 4.10.2

nuxt 2.3.4
@nuxtjs/axios 5.3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。

下記でwebpackのプロジェクトを作成し、

```
$ vue init webpack プロジェクト名
```

npmビルドすることで、distフォルダにindex.htmlとstaticフォルダが作成されました。

```
$ npm run build
```

このindex.htmlとstaticフォルダをspring bootのsrc\main\resourcesに格納することで
spring bootを起動した際に、indexページを表示してくれました。

dockerでもうまくいきました。